# Find parent with certain combination of child rows - SQLite with Python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

There are several parts to this question. I am working with sqlite3 in Python 2.7, but I am less concerned with the exact syntax, and more with the methods I need to use. I think the best way to ask this question is to describe my current database design, and what I am trying to accomplish. I am new to databases in general, so I apologize if I don't always use correct nomenclature.

I am modeling refrigeration systems (using Modelica--not really important to know), and I am using the database to manage input data, results data, and models used for that data.

My top parent table is `Model`, which contains the columns:

```
id, name, version, date_created
```

My child table under `Model` is called `Design`. It is used to create a unique id for each combination of design input parameters and the model used. the columns it contains are:

```
id, model_id, date_created
```

I then have two child tables under `Design`, one called `Input`, and the other called `Result`. We can just look at Input for now, since one example should be enough. The columns for input are:

```
id, value, design_id, parameter_id, component_id
```

`parameter_id` and `component_id` are foreign keys to their own tables.The `Parameter` table has the following columns:

```
id, name, units
```

Some example rows for `Parameter under` name are: length, width, speed, temperature, pressure (there are many dozens more). The Component table has the following columns:

```
id, name
```

Some example rows for `Component` under name are: compressor, heat_exchanger, valve.

Ultimately, in my program I want to search the database for a specific design. I want to be able to search a specific design to be able to grab specific results for that design, or to know whether or not a model simulation with that design has already been run previously, to avoid re-running the same data point.

I also want to be able to grab all the parameters for a given design, and insert it into a class I have created in Python, which is then used to provide inputs to my models. In case it helps for solving the problem, the classes I have created are based on the components. So, for example, I have a compressor class, with attributes like compressor.speed, compressor.stroke, compressor.piston_size. Each of these attributes should have their own row in the Parameter table.

So, how would I query this database efficiently to find if there is a design that matches a long list (let's assume 100+) of parameters with specific values? Just as a side note, my friend helped me design this database. He knows databases, but not my application super well. It is possible that I designed it poorly for what I want to accomplish.

Here is a simple picture trying to map a certain combination of parameters with certain values to a design_id, where I have taken out component_id for simplicity:

[Picture of simplified tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M33DW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply join the necessary tables. Your schema properly reflects normalization (separating tables into logical groupings) and can scale for one-to-many relationships. Specifically, to answer your question --*So, how would I query this database efficiently to find if there is a design that matches a long list (let's assume 100+) of parameters with specific values?*-- consider below approaches:

**Inner Join with Where Clause**

For handful of parameters, use an inner join with a `WHERE...IN()` clause. Below returns *design* fields joined by *input* and *parameters* tables, filtered for specific parameter names where you can have Python pass as parameterized values even iteratively in a loop:

```sql
SELECT d.id, d.model_id, d.date_created
FROM design d
INNER JOIN input i ON d.id = i.design_id
INNER JOIN parameters p ON p.id = i.parameter_id
WHERE p.name IN ('param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4', 'param5', ...)
```

**Inner Join with Temp Table**

Should values be over 100+ in a long list, consider a temp table that filters *parameters* table to specific parameter values:

```
# CREATE EMPTY TABLE (SAME STRUCTURE AS parameters)
sql = "CREATE TABLE tempparams AS SELECT id, name, units FROM parameters WHERE 0;"
cur.execute(sql)
db.commit()

# ITERATIVELY APPEND TO TEMP
for i in paramslist:                                  # LIST OF 100+ ITEMS
    sql = "INSERT INTO tempparams (id, name, units) \
           SELECT p.id, p.name, p.units \
           FROM parameters p \
           WHERE p.name = ?;"
    cur.execute(sql, i)                               # CURSOR OBJECT COMMAND PASSING PARAM
    db.commit()                                       # DB OBJECT COMMIT ACTION
```

Then, join main *design* and *input* tables with new temp table holding specific parameters:

```sql
SELECT d.id, d.model_id, d.date_created
FROM design d
INNER JOIN input i ON d.id = i.design_id
INNER JOIN tempparams t ON t.id = i.parameter_id
```

Same process can work with *components* table as well.

*Moved picture to question section

Comment: Thanks, this did help me some, but I need more help. 

What you have here will select many parameters, but I need to select a set of parameters with specific values.

I was trying to do this by adding a lot of AND'S in the WHERE statement. First I join the tables, and then I select, e.g.: WHERE p.name = 'length' AND i.value = 10 AND p.name = 'width' AND i.value = 5 AND ...

As you can probably guess, this leads to no selected values, because it is trying to find a row which contains all of these conditions.

Comment: You may need `OR` between pairings but `AND` within: `WHERE (p.name = 'length' AND i.value = 10) OR (p.name = 'width' AND  i.value = 5) OR...` And if too many pairings in `WHERE` clause, consider a temp table where you iteratively build, then join to main tables.

Comment: If I do that, it will find design_id's with any of those parameter name + value combo, while I want to find design_id's only where all of the parameter name + value combos are satisfied. I added a picture above to show an example. In that example, I may want to find all design_id's where parameter_id = 1 with a value=3.2 AND parameter_id=2 with a value=1.8 AND parameter_id=3 with a value=1.3 AND parameter_id=4 with a value=1.2. The code I am trying to write would then tell me that design_id=1 matches these conditions.

Comment: Did you run the suggestion I commented above?